# How do I get a decreased-by-one \x in a foreach loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, loops

My problem is pretty much complicated than this one, but the point is pretty similar.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (1,3);
\coordinate (A3) at (5,1);
\coordinate (A4) at (2,-1);
\foreach \x in {2,3,4} {\draw (A\x) -- (A\x-1);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The thing is that I need to use the variable `\x` to be increased or decreased (or calculated) and to remain attached to the A. `A\x` works nice but I cannot get `A\x-1` to work.

Answer (score 8):

Use `(A\the\numexpr\x-1\relax)` to perform the operation inline.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (1,3);
\coordinate (A3) at (5,1);
\coordinate (A4) at (2,-1);
\foreach \x in {2,3,4} {\draw (A\x) -- (A\the\numexpr\x-1\relax);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a function difference to the solution of wang ki wun? Just curious, it's no critics.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Wang's solution is arguably better for this simple MWE.  However, the actual question was how to subtract 1 from `\x` inside a `tikz` loop, which my answer provides.

Comment: That's right. The issue was not how to plot the picture but how to deal with increasing the variable.

Answer (score 6):

You only need one coordinate and draw the line in one go:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (1,3);
\coordinate (A3) at (5,1);
\coordinate (A4) at (2,-1);

\draw (A1) \foreach \x in {2,3,4} {-- (A\x)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Will also give better joints as shrodingers cat noted

Answer (score 5):

It is not a good idea to split the path in single `\draw` commands, the line joins won't look good. Rather, I'd suggest

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (1,3);
\coordinate (A3) at (5,1);
\coordinate (A4) at (2,-1);
\draw plot[samples at={1,2,3,4}] (A\x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```